# Does superfish module support multiple languages?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, navigation

Does superfish module support multiple languages in drupal 7?  From the CMS, I seem to be able to translate each menu item into english and french.  But Superfish is only outputting the english version of the menu.  So does superfish handle multiple languages?  If it does, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At time of writing this response, the answer is NO.  superfish doesn't have multilingual support for drupal 7.  I couldn't find a patch.  So i stopped using superfish.

Answer (score 2):

Heh, it looks like they've released a version of [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) with what was supposed to be just a temporarily disabled support for translations.

You can either

1. apply patch found at http://drupal.org/node/1112928 or
2. use an older version of Superfish

Comment: actually, i noticed that with superfish, it prints urls as /node/111, but elsewhere on my drupal site (other modules), it will print urls as /fr/accuiel.  Both point to the same place.  Is it NOT-IDEAL to be using /node/111, and hence, considered a super-fish bug?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that i18n is supported, or at least improved using [this patch](http://drupal.org/node/1381542).

Answer (score 1):

I've tested first with version 7.x-1.8 and it didn't work, the superfish menu was returned with both language of the site, but with version superfish-7.x-1.9-beta4 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Version superfish-7.x-1.9-beta4 worked.